# Angular function instead of method call. Why?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I work on code snippet described on https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[] = [];
  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
  }
}
```

And my question about this code part:

```
.then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
```

is it possible to create a method in DashboardComponent and pass it as argument instead of function? Is the functional approach here anything better than a method inside DashboardComponent class?

Comment: Sure it's possible. `.then(this.onGetHeroes.bind(this))`.

Comment: One line arrow function seems to be used for terseness. One line instead of multiple when adding another method.

Comment: @deceze why you used bind method.? Is it not enough to put in method 
 body this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5) ?

Comment: Because: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/476)

Comment: Oh thanks! I thought this is not the case when using typescript. Probably this is my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why using arrow functions.
Most of them are just a matter of style & readability.

Beside that, there is one important difference: if you would be passing components method to it then you would need to bind contrxt for `this` to that method.
With arrow function thats not needed as they dont create new context.